# Create a single use link

Tags: web-services, security

I'm writing a database front end for a website.  Next to the records I want to include a link likes this:

```
 Record 1 - [Add][1] [Edit][2] [Delete][3]
```

But I want to protect these links from being used more than once.  My thinking is to pass a hash value then store a list of valid HASH values in a table somewhere and only process requests with valid hash values.  Is there a better way to do is?

Update:  The answer to this question led me to ask this question:  [What is the difference between a "nonce" and a "GUID"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-nonce-and-a-guid).  Why exactly would you use a nonce instead of a GUID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct, except that you should use cryptographically secure random bytes (a ["nonce"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)) instead of a hash.

Comment: I'm hoping to find some method that would allow me to determine wether this was a first-time request without hitting the database.  That would help protect from DOS attacks as well.

Comment: I've read a little more about "nonce" value.  Is it really the same idea as using a hash, but using the nonce value as the hash?  For example, if I created GUID values using the perl Data::GUID module and used those for hash values would that be "nonce"?

Comment: The point of the nonce is to be unpredictable.  If you use a hash, you should use a keyed HMAC SHA 512 hash with a random key, and you should change the key frequently.