# What is the difference between a "nonce" and a "GUID"?

Tags: security, guid

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066611/what-are-best-practices-for-activation-registration-password-reset-links-in-email) is about creating an authentication scheme.  The accepted answer given by AviD states

> Your use of a cryptographic nonce is
>   also important, that many tend to skip
>   over - e.g. "lets just use a GUID"...

---

Which leads me to my question.  Why wouldn't you just use a GUID?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you randomly generate a random number intended to be used in cryptography, you should be *really* sure that the number is *really* random. GUIDs tend to be generated based on values that can be discovered, guessed or inferred, such as current system time or a network card MAC address, and thus the nonce could potentially be guessed.

Answer (score 3):

Nonces should be random (or at least non-guessable).  GUIDs have quite a bit of non-randomness to them (I'm not sure how many bits of entropy are in a GUID).

Comment: There being varying definitions of what exactly constitutes a GUID and how they are generated, the hypothetical question "How many bits of entropy are in a GUID?" is almost worthless. Worse, I don't think any of the definitions set clear standards for the generation of randomness, so all the randomness in a GUID might, in theory, have come from seeding a PRNG with a coin flip.